# How can I add multiple WinForms Toolbox Controls from one VSIX Project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2019

I followed this; [Create a Windows Forms Toolbox Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-windows-forms-toolbox-control?view=vs-2019) from msdn, and was able to successfully create my own custom toolbox control and install it and use it. Perfect.
*But*, when I try to add *another* control file to it-for example in solution explorer I have ProjectName and then inside of that I have CustomToolboxControl1.cs(which works fine) and then I have CustomToolboxControl2.cs. CustomToolboxControl2.cs; for whatever reason does not appear in the toolbox, everything compiles fine with no compile or runtime errors, and I set it up exactly like I did the first one.

I've tried searching Google, YouTube, StackOverflow(Which I came across a few "solutions" that didn't work for me 'cause it was way outdated from like '08 and such), and can not for the life of me find out how to add multiple custom WinForms UserControls from **one** VSIX project. Not sure if I'm just not wording my searches correctly or not but...Here I am, makin' my first post here on StackOverflow. Hopefully I'm doin' this question thing right, it seems like a lot of SO posts I come across are people just getting anal in the comments about how the question was asked lol.

Here's some images that will hopefully further help:

The controls are CoffeeComboBox(the one that works) and CoffeeTabControl(the one not showing up in toolbox but compiles fine and is setup the same way as the other one):

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPE6t.png)

And here's what it looks like in the debugging instance of Visual Studio Toolbox:

[Visual Studio Debug Instance Toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnJsH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it.

I did everything correctly, but the Visual Studio Instance was just buggy. I decided to close VS, try installing the VSIX project anyways, and then testing it on an actual new WinForm project rather than just a debug instance of VS. It showed up just fine in the toolbox there. Was able to drag both of my custom tools that were properly placed under the specified custom tab, from the toolbox to the form just fine.

**For anyone else that may come across this question**, to further elaborate;
If you [**follow this guide to Create a Windows Forms Toolbox Control**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-windows-forms-toolbox-control?view=vs-2019) from the msdn(Microsoft Documentation) site, just rinse and repeat for any additional UserControl WinForms Controls that you want to add. To do that; **Right click the project name** > **Add** > **New Item...** > **Extensibility** > **Windows Forms Toolbox Control** > **giveItAName.cs** > **Click Add** bottom right. Done.

Closed.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.